# How to make the IEEETrans references compact?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using the following document class and I want to make each reference entry compact (2 lines).
Is there a way to do this automatically, or do I have to manually edit each reference?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! // One possible way is to limit the number of authors, say 1 author or 3. All other authors are changed to `and others` in the `.bib` file. Maybe Editing it manually is better since you may decide how many authors you want to keep. // Also keep the journal in abbreviation as is required by IEEE. `IEEEabrv.bib` would help if you are citing IEEE journal papers.

Comment: We don't even know what bibliography style you're using now. Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we can experiment with.